# jQuery - Image replacement transition [issues in Safari]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay I have the following code:-

[[SEE JSFIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/khqmp26g/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <span class="mobile-menu"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  height: 100px;
}

.mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 20px;
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 26px !important;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.mobile-menu-hover {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/mobile-menu-hover.png);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var imagesArray = ["http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-02.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-03.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-04.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-05.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-06.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-07.png"];

function preloadImg(pictureUrls, callback) {
  var i, j, loaded = 0;
  var imagesArray = [];

  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    imagesArray.push(new Image());
  }
  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    (function (img, src) {
      img.onload = function () {
        if (++loaded == pictureUrls.length && callback) {
          callback(imagesArray);
        }
      };
      img.src = src;
    }(imagesArray[i], pictureUrls[i]));
  }
};


function changeImage(background, imagesArray, index, reverse) {
  background.css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[index].src + "')").fadeIn(10, function() {
    if (reverse) {
      index--;
      if (index == -1) {
        return; // stop the interval
      }
    } else {
      index++;
      if (index == imagesArray.length) {
        return; // stop the interval
      }
    }
    //Fade in the top element
    background.fadeOut(10, function () {
      //Set the background of the top element to the new background
      background.css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[index] + "')");
      changeImage(background, imagesArray, index, reverse);
    });
  });
}



jQuery(function () {
  /* Preload Image */
  preloadImg(imagesArray, function (imagesArray) {
    jQuery(".mobile-menu").css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[0].src + "')")
    jQuery('.mobile-menu').on('click', {imgs: imagesArray}, function (event) {
      var background = jQuery(".mobile-menu");
      var bi = background.css('background-image');
      var index = 0;
      var reverse = false;
      if (imagesArray[0].src != bi.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '')) {
        index = imagesArray.length - 1;
        reverse = true;
      }
      changeImage(background, event.data.imgs, index, reverse);
    });
  });
});
```

**The Issue:**

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, it transitions between the 7 different images on click, then does the reverse on the second click (toggling).

The problem is when I try this in Safari, it basically goes through the image replacement process then reverts back to the first image for some reason and I can't figure out why?

Any ideas?

Comment: It's really strange, it starts ever from the last image and not from the first image. I think it's an issue with `on('click', {imgs: imagesArray}....` but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because Safari returns the **background-image** without double quotes, but your replace function checks for url(**"**, so it doesn't replace and reverse never gets true.

Instead of replacing you can check using either **indexOf** or matching using a RegExp, it would be safer and more straightforward. Either:

```
if ( bi.indexOf(imagesArray[0].src) == -1) {
```

or

```
 if (imagesArray[0].src != bi.match(/http.+png/)[0]) {
```

With indexOf: http://jsfiddle.net/u9ske14r/